# emacs in ssh shell on windows

Tags: emacs

I want to cut a region, however C+space is not working on my windows box (ssh to a linux server). it merely indents a space.
what to do?

Comment: You could also try to work out how to map that key sequence correctly, provided the terminal is sending it at all. The following Q&A (and its associated links) is more Unix-centric, but it might prove useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623630/emacs-control-shift-up-doesnt-work/4624332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd>.