# paredit keybindings with GUI vs terminal emacs

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, paredit

I'm struggling with this odd behaviour; paredit's commands of interest, namely **paredit-forward-slurp-sexp**, bound to **C-),** and **paredit-forward-barf-sexp**, bound to **C-}**, as well as their "backwards" counterparts, work in a GUI emacs, but don't work in terminal one. The functions themselves do work, but not their keybindings. From running C-h f:

```
paredit-forward-slurp-sexp is an interactive compiled Lisp function in                                                 
‘paredit.el’.                                                                                                          

It is bound to <C-right>, C-).
```

not sure what's wrong, but it sure doesn't appear to be bound to those. All the other common keybindings seem to be working as promised, but not these ones. Don't even know where to start exploring.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732424/emacs-keybinding-doesnt-work-in-terminal  TLDR: the terminal aliases some keypresses, Emacs gets keypresses from the terminal, so figure out how to make your terminal not alias the keys or use the GUI.

Comment: thanks, mate! I suspected something like that. Replacing Mac's native Terminal with ITerm2 solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to the comment above, the problem was indeed the terminal-to-emacs transmission of keypresses; replacing native Mac Terminal with ITerm2 solved it.