# Why are paredit keybindings showing incorrect instructions in emacs

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, paredit

I installed paredit in emacs (gui not terminal and no spacemacs or doomemacs, just emacs) and then checked some of the commands and their corresponding key bindings.
Ex. `paredit-forward-slurp-sexp C-<right>`

[image: image from emacs showing keybinding that start with paredit-forward-]

I believe the `<right>` is the right arrow on the keyboard.  In other emacs configurations like spacemacs, `C-<right>` worked.

However, I noticed the commands `paredit-forward-slurp-sexp` worked but the key bindings `C-<right>` did not.

Then I found a paredit [cheatsheet](https://github.com/georgek/paredit-cheatsheet/blob/master/paredit-cheatsheet-refcard.pdf) that had different key bindings that worked.
Ex. `paredit-forward-slurp-sexp C-)`
[image: part of a cheatsheet showing emacs binding for paredit-forward-slurp-sexp]

So my question again, why are the keybinding for paredit in emacs that are actually displayed in emacs when you start to write `M-x paredit-forward-` then tab to see what options that are available, showing the commands with incorrect keybindings?

**Note**:

I did look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357663/paredit-keybindings-with-gui-vs-terminal-emacs) that speaks about the difference in aliased keybindings in gui vs terminal emacs (depending on the terminal).  However, when I tried to use any of the key bindings in the terminal, none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a few reasons why the paredit keybindings are showing incorrect instructions in Emacs. One possibility is that the keybindings may be conflicting with other keybindings in your Emacs configuration. Another possibility is that there may be a bug or issue with the paredit package itself.

To troubleshoot this issue, you could try resetting your Emacs configuration to its default settings and then reinstalling the paredit package to see if the keybindings work correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Presently I am using the keybindings from the cheatsheet, as I am finishing up some work, but will try resetting things.

Comment: You're welcome! If you continue to experience issues with the keybindings despite resetting your configuration, please add comment anytime. Good luck with your work!