# C-<SPC> is intercepted in emacs -nw (terminal intercept?)

Tags: emacs, terminal, key-bindings, gnome-terminal, rxvt

I use urxvt (terminal) under awesome (window manager) and ubuntu (os).
In graphical mode, c- set the mark but in text mode it inserts a space.
The problem is solved when using gnome-terminal but some other key combinations still does not work.  For instance, C-: insert a : in both terminals.
I do not know where to look at to correct this behaviour.
C-h k (help on key combination) followed by one of these combination shows only the key pressed along ctrl, for instance C- is interpreted as .

As stated in comments, the terminal is probably the cause. I believe that C- should not enter a space at the terminal prompt, which it does here.

I identified [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4167296/1266155) as being related. [This one too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11110801/1266155).

Comment: I didn't find about gnome-terminal. Personally I abandoned that workflow. I work almost exclusively in Emacs + an emacs M-x shell. I like the fact that it is a normal buffer too, I can open pdf and images, I browse files with dired, I listen to music with mpg123, I call a shell with shell-pop, I have tabs with elscreen, etc (some nice tips: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Shell).

Comment: I need the text version of emacs to work over ssh.

Comment: You can use tramp to work over ssh.  Regarding your question, I don't think it is an Emacs issue but something related to your terminal (how it translate key combination to keycodes).  Maybe your chances of find an expert on that will improve if you add some labels to your question related to text terminals.

Comment: I too work sometimes over ssh from emacs' shell-mode (to get a SQL prompt or similar).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, Ctrl-Space was being used to change input methods. Running `ibus-setup` and unbinding it fixed my problem (it now produces Nul)

See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/243639/ctrlspace-has-been-bound-to-invoke-some-input-method-and-does-not-work-in-ema

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. My problem is probably something else as I do not use ibus.