# emacs + konsole: key binding problems

Tags: emacs, archlinux, konsole

Hi everyone,

I recently installed konsole on my arch linux because of a problem on xfce4-terminal (sometimes the terminal doesn't refresh after typing a command, or in a middle of a yaourt output... I thought of a problem of encoding but im in utf8 and it works flawlessly on other terminals, with the same zsh configuration..)
Anyway, I really like konsole, but I have a big problem:
I am used to launch emacs directly in the term (-nw), and most of emacs's shortcuts aren't working anymore:

- shift +arrow doesn't do anything
- control + arrow moves from one char instead of word
- ctrl + shift doesn't work either.

Anyone have an idea why it behaves like this?

Comment: Take a look at some of the threads about Emacs keybindings in terminal emulators (eg [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309580/emacs-key-bindings-change-in-terminal-emulator?lq=1)).  The problem is that many emulators don't send the control and escape sequences you want.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate,
And thanks for the answer, i'll look into it