# C-<SPC> just inserts a space emacs - tty console

Tags: linux, emacs, console, key-bindings, tty

I have this problem in emacs when using it in console: when pressing C- it just inserts a space instead of invoking the set-mark function as it should. The control key works in console, as other key combination including CTRL key work (e.g C-h-b, C-x C-c).

Under X every keybinding works correctly, so I suppose it is not an emacs problem, but rather a console related one. Does anybody have an idea at least where to start to look for a solution?

edit: thanks for the links but it doesn't work either

after hitting C-h l (shows the keys input to emacs) I noticed that emacs doesn't get C-space at all, just space. But emacs still gets the other Ctrl keys combinations correctly. I am using the linux console, and as far as I know (correct me if I'm wrong) it's not an emulator: it is the terminal. Unfortunately I have no idea how to fix this annoying bug, as I find emacs very useful.

Comment: What do you see if you do a `C-h k C-<space>`? Does emacs just see a bare space character, or another modifier that just isn't bound to anything special? If Control works everywhere else in the console, I'm not sure you can rule out emacs so easily. But you can also mess around with the keymaps in /usr/share/kbd/keymaps (load a new one with `loadkeys`) and see if you can figure out what's happening.

Comment: It's most likely a terminal emulation problem, since they don't necessarily see the control sequences you're sending.  Take a look at [this related thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309580/emacs-key-bindings-change-in-terminal-emulator) (and the links therein) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

> But you can also mess around with the keymaps in /usr/share/kbd/keymaps (load a new one with loadkeys) and see if you can figure out what's happening.

Thanks deong :), that solved my problem: I loaded another compatible keymap with `loadkeys other-keymap'.
I didn't think about it because CTRL worked everywhere else. So am I to understand that in the previous non-working keymap "Ctrl-space" was mapped to "space"?